# Rest assured path not able to access element with number in path

Tags: json, rest-assured, gpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

In the following (partial)JSON response:

```
    {
      "costPrices": {
        "3226186": [
          {
            "fromDate": 1420066800000,
            "toDate": null,
            "product": {
```

I'm trying to access the value of fromDate like this:

```
    body("costPrices.3226186[0].fromDate", equalTo(1420066800000L))
```

But when it comes to the number in the path expression it fails, is there some way around this?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: 3226186 @ line 1, column 40.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. With rest-assured's jsonPath, writing

```
"costPrices.3226186[0].fromDate"
```

means *gather all the `3226186` properties from the objects in the array `costPrices` and then choose the first one*.

In your case, what you want is:

```
body("costPrices.3226186.fromDate[0]", equalTo(1420066800000L))
```